# Raspberry pi3 and django

Tags: django, raspberry-pi3, pythonanywhere

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to take the sensor values using raspberry pi 3 store it in cloud or in raspberry pi 3 and I should be able to access that data and display it on a django based server( we are asked to use pythonanywhere.com which is a django app ) . The data should be taken from sensors after some interval of time.

Comment: what have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: What is your question? How to get the sensor values? How to store it on the cloud? How to display it from the server? You need to identify a specific problem, what approach you want to use, and where you are stuck. See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this website  you will get plenty of examples 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/resources/

Comment: Thanks, this has the answer I need.